# How to programmatically open application using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio, subprocess

feel free to change the code that I have tried before, to make a solution. Anything will help. The main purpose of this is the user would type the file they would like to open and the computer would look through the user folders and find the .exe of the app and open. Thought I could do this by looping through the user file explorer but didn't work like I expected. So I tried `os.system`... Didn't work either. Then did some research and stumbled up to `os.startfile()`. Out of ideas. But I feel Like the issue is the way I wrote what file to look directory to look at. Help

```
usersiterequest = input()



import os
import subprocess


#os.system(usersiterequest)

#def find_files(filename, search_path):
   #result = []

# Walking top-down from the root
   #for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      #if filename in files:
         #result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
         #open = subprocess.Popen(filename)
         #return subprocess.Popen(result)
#local = 'C:\'
#find_files('usersiterequest','shell:AppsFolder:')
#print(find_files("smpl.htm","D:"))

#
#local = 'C:\Program Files' + usersiterequest

#print(local)
#os.startfile(local);
#import os
#import subprocess

command  = r"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\." + usersiterequest;
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Have you tried r"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\" + usersiterequest; (as in, no final period in string)? May be a Windows thing. Could also be a permissions issue.

I would imagine a simple version of this program would just run a find command for the user input, then run that file, but you'll have to look up the Windows version of the find command. I can post the bare minimum Linux working version I have if that helps.

Comment: Also, could you post the things you tried and for each of them what error or output you got?

Comment: There was not any error. Just didn't get the needed result. I expected the app to open. Instead the computer told me the app doesn't excite

Comment: I would try an app in a different folder location like C:\User\your_account\Downloads\ so that you can test in a folder that doesn't have permission issues. Also, I tried your code in my Windows computer. I think you need to use the command "start <program_name>" to run a program.

Comment: What IDE did you use when using that command?

Comment: Just the windows command prompt.